# Shimano Sport Camera ANT+ Software

Tags: shimano, camera, ant+

I own the Shimano sport camera, which per specs, will read speed, cadence and heart rate via ANT+. I am told that the data from the devices is recorded onto a .csv file that is stored on the card with the video. To put the two together, you are supposed to use software from Shimano. I can't find a download link anywhere online.

Does anyone know if the above procedure is correct, and when Shimano will be releasing the software?

I need to buy an ANT+ HRM and cadence/speed sensor but am not going to waste the money if they aren't going to release it this year.

*Camera Info: http://bike.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/articles/shimano-sport-camera.html*

Answer (score 1):

The first result on google is http://www.shimano-sportcamera.com/us/application.php - if you click the little youtube video, it shows how to integrate Ant+ sensors and the video.

Answer (score 1):

There is no video editing software from Shimano.

The CSV is present, you should see it if you paired your sensors in the mobile app.

I have used DashWare with success with my Shimano action camera, others have reported Garmin VIRB edit software works but I have not tried.

Comment: I don't own this camera but this answer appears to be confirmed on the CyclingTips web site -http://cyclingtips.com.au/2014/07/shimano-sport-camera-review/

Answer (score 1):

You can use any ANT+ HRM strap and/or cadence/speed sensors. Garmin and others sell ANT+ compatible units. You don't have to wait for Shimano to release their own.